# Seperate email contents and turn into MYSQL data PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Here is an example:

```
Customer: Bob Smith 
Account: 1234
Address: 123 Main St
City: Anywhere, USA
```

I would like to convert this into a MYSQL table, where I would have Customer, Account, Address, and City Columns.

I am not the best way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Are the emails sent automatically from a form submission? Do you control the script that sends them? If not can you trust the contents to be consistently formatted?

Comment: They are not from a form submission.  I do not control how they are sent but it is in a controlled environment.  The emails are auto generated from a server and the format will not change.

Comment: There are about a million ways to do this from scraping to simply exploding the text into an array. What you're asking for is a database layout with insertion code and you've not put forth any effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may parse your text like that:

```
$str = "Customer: Bob Smith Account: 1234 Address: 123 Main St City: Anywhere, USA";
preg_match("/Customer\\:(.*)Account\\:(.*)Address\\:(.*)City\\:(.*)/",$str,$matches);
$customer = $matches[1];
$account = $matches[2];
$address = $matches[3];
$city= $matches[4];
```

After this process. You can send to mysql easily :)

Comment: Thank you for the help.  That is basically what I am looking for.  Any ideas on scraping the actual email?  I have been researching imap_fetchbody to accomplish this